# Where on iTunes Connect I can add additional App info?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I distributed an iOS app on AppStore, but the app was rejected because we are requesting permission for user location in background.

I already answered the reviewer many times explaining why we need to use background location for our users, and I also added a disclaimer in the application description as stated on other questions here on stack overflow informing the user that the usage of GPS in background can increase battery depletion speed. But the app is still being rejected for the same reason that is Apple performance guideline 2.5.4.

```
2.5.4 Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc. If your app uses location background mode, include a reminder that doing so may dramatically decrease battery life.
```

I noticed that apps that request user location in background have an additional Information field called Location.

[App with Location field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOiGG.png)

But my app does not contain that field

[App without Location field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcin2.png)

So I presume, that instead of adding that disclaimer on the app description on iTunes Connect form, I should place it somewhere else, but looking at my iTunes Connect account on App Information [session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZUUA.png) there is no text field where I can input that information. And consulting Apple Docs I also wasn't able to find where I should input that.

So my question is where I can set that information that is shown on iTunes, via iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is where I can set that information that is shown on iTunes, via iTunes Connect?

Nowhere. Apple adds that, not you.

> I already answered the reviewer many times explaining why we need to use background location for our users

Well, that is what you need to attend to. You are evidently trying to use background location in some skanky way, and you are busted. So use background location legitimately or not at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.The reason why I need the permission is because we use IBM Mobile Push SDK. and we use beacon and geofence internally to send users push notification of promotions and physical stores nearby based on their location. Still even after explaining that they are refusing the app. We had to disable push notification entirely to submit a bugfix recently.

Comment: Another weird thing is that they approved before and we released 5 versions of our app with that permission enabled, and just now they decided to reject the app.

Comment: Okay but that’s not a Stack Overflow matter.